# How do you get excel to ignore zero or blank values in an Average?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, data-validation

I am making a spreadsheet to score recipe ingredients, averaging scores for quality of the ingredient, packaging, and accuracy of serving size, and then using that data to create an average for the whole recipe.

The scores are filled in through data validation. 1=Bad, 2=Fair, 3=Good. The `AVERAGE` formula works fine when **all**  of the fields are input through the dropdowns, but if any of the rows are left with all blank values I get a `DIV/0` error in the column I am attempting to get average in (`E8:E19` ) as well as the average for the entire recipe (`B20`). I tried to do `AVERAGEIF`, but that didn't work and I am stumped. Every recipe has a different number of ingredients, so it is important that this function works whether I have one ingredient or 20.

I tried to upload a screenshot but the site won't let me.

Comment: Then post the image on some imagesharing site, and add a link to it. It would also be helpful if you showed us e.g. what you had tried to do with `AVERAGEIF`

Comment: Average normally does ignore blank cells. It must have something to do with filling in through data valuation.

Comment: *AVERGAE()* will ignore **some** blanks, but if there are **only** blanks, what would you like the formula to return ??

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the error-catch function in Excel? As you have said, if you take the average of only blank cells, Excel will provide a result of Div/0.

Let's say there are 3 people (A,B,C) reviewing a recipe for Guacamole. Let's say the csv looks something like this:

Ingredient,Score A, Score B, Score C

Avocado,1,2,3

Cilanto,,,

Lime,1,2,3

Tomato,1,2,3

When you calculate the average for each ingredient, use a formula like this:
=IF(ISERROR(AVERAGE('ingredient score range')=TRUE),"",AVERAGE('ingredient score range')

All this formula is doing is saying if the average of the ingredient scores is an error, leave it blank. Otherwise, calculate the average.

Then you should be able to average all of the scores of your ingredients without a problem. You also have the option of scoring an ingredient as 0 rather than blank. This would of course change the math in the average for the recipe.

Answer (score 0):

`IFERROR` is a very convenient function;

- ```
  IFERROR(calculated_value, default_value)
  ```

  is short for
- ```
  IF(ISERROR(calculated_value), default_value, calculated_value)
  ```

i.e., it substitutes a default value (typically a *non*-error value)
for an error value.  So you probably want something like

```
IFERROR(AVERAGE(E8:E19), "")
```

replacing the `""` with whatever you want to get
when `E8:E19` is all non-numeric.